# Typing callback functions based on variable inputs

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Take the following code (admittedly a contrived example):

```
arbitraryFunction(
    // Dynamically generated input
    [
        returnValue("key1", "a"), 
        returnValue("key2", 1),
        returnValue("key3", ()=>{})
    ],

    // Callback, parameters are typed against input
    (value : {key1: string, key2: number, key3: Function} )=>{
        return value 
    }

)
```

I'm hoping to type the `value` parameter in the callback in reference the the given input.

So for example, this callback function would be rejected:

```
// key1's type is string, not number!
(value : {key1: number} )=>{}
```

I've tried using generics, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anybody have any insight on if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this can be done. You need to use recursive array iteration within your generics to iterate through the array of ReturnValues to build up the parameters for the callback.

Let me know if there's something you want further explanation on as there's a lot in here!

```js
function returnValue<K extends string, T>(key: K, type: T): [K, T] {
    return [key, type];
}

type ReturnValue = ReturnType<typeof returnValue>;

type GenerateCallbackParams<I extends readonly ReturnValue[], P = {}> =
    // Base case where we have one item left in I
    I extends  readonly [infer R]
        ? R extends [infer K, infer T]
            ? K extends string 
                // Merge params with K: T
                ? P & { [key in K]: T }
                : P
            : never
        // When multiple array elements in I
        : I extends readonly [infer R, ...(infer Tail)]
            ? R extends [infer K, infer T]
                ? K extends string
                    ? Tail extends ReturnValue[]
                        ? GenerateCallbackParams<Tail, P & { [key in K]: T }>
                        : never
                    : never
                : never
            : never;

function arbitraryFunction<I extends readonly ReturnValue[]>(inputParams: I, callback: (params: GenerateCallbackParams<I>) => GenerateCallbackParams<I>) {

}

// Has to be declared as const here otherwise TS widens the type inside the array
const params = [
    returnValue("key1", "a"), 
    returnValue("key2", 1),
    returnValue("key3", ()=>{})
] as const;

arbitraryFunction(
    // Dynamically generated input
    params,

    // Callback, parameters are typed against input
    ({ key1, key2, key3}) => {
        typeof key1; // string
        typeof key2; // number
        typeof key3; // () => void
        return { key1, key2, key3 };
    }
)
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKZRMsA1AhgGxFQB4BpRVADylTABMBnRBqZGMAcwBpEAVAPgAUAa1QBPAFyJSPKGIAOqKbwCUUgNoy%20AXUQBvAFCJjKdJiTrRY2QtTaA3AYC%20Bg3MWIASmax5CqRABeLx8wXltid1Q4YFMMXwIifkc3W0QAcVpUZFwaAGECfAAjXAhhAAVcHIBbBmIASQpqWkZTXDoEfDEQ%20JxE1HVtHnKg-Sd%20IKMTAHppxAAhXAYAiCWAgHcAC2yNgM3cADcAhACYGmrEfFRgKER2RHqp40aqGnomNo6wLsR1dmBsl5tE8TMYAPxeJpvVp-MAA5DSHj-QG8YGg9EmCHkV4tJgsNicRAgjEY2aIACy2Q4AXkVVwtUQ6zOm2kymJJNBEJGADJ9L8rHckKRtMpEC4ORypOV2RipGBUEdkDLEGSAOrbJDVED4KDyK6IKo5bqoK7VWhQJj3R6Sh5Q3GfTrdWHwrw8AB0HsEyIRvFwMHwKjREvBkJx71%203sRgpdqOVHKxdvD%20PYHDjwcQEN9-sTrW8vT8REGafTmIyWRy%20UKJTKlRqdSz%20GGiF5en54kF0hFfDF-GLJcQcoV2T7NvlipHJkH45LU%20yKVAkFgCANyCKZxyyDEADFwNB4GAGjmmGh2o6euYCwNtEJ2PIQFBa-SGFJ6jxVvhiqVhFJBLS61JMnlCtUAKD9qwqOlagafgVCCCZAOyXIQKrL9Hyg%20oYP0VwXAMMkAAklkQKA4EQIoAjoVAIHwKpUDoA0mAgBAWEQbY0EQOAoFYpllj4ABlRkYAosAmE4gIokFBhBLE7YVyNAxGOE24-yfUZ1BBNB836QQACIrAARm0nhtNwbSVB4dTQkvHSrAAJkMxA9LMizNP8azxAAZnswQVECfg9CcFQDF0QiFJYFIqjXVgqm3XclzAQQQTJAARMQwHpGB3x%20akgKQujb3vEFlNqLhXFBMlQM-MoeCK9BsiYGiiNsOjcA4P1FMFO8oBBQRW30nhbP6jyArgrCOSiGJEH0%20wVTmZNOGVcbYls6ayTAEBqjIpUxtsCarHcla5m8kaDjgQTlQ08w%20T6ybxBswaxHcsVHFBFxAqAA)